# Problem with simultaneous clicks from different users

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

I've got a website that allows users to join a "team". The team has a member limit defined in `$maxPlayersPerTeam`.

When the user clicks the link to join a team this code gets executed

```
//query to get players count
if ($players < $maxPlayersPerTeam) {
  // query to insert the player
}
```

However, if two users click the join link at the same time, both can join the team even if `$players` is equal to `$maxPlayersPerTeam`.

What can I do to avoid this?

Comment: You should mention how you're updating the number of players; how is that stored?

Comment: Is `$maxPlayersPerTeam` retrieved just before you execute the `if` statement?

Comment: Have you actually ran into this problem? The scenario of 2 users joining at the same time is "almost" impossible.

Comment: [Bad Idea] you could implement a backend job distribution system (e.g. Gearman) to handle the task of adding users without allowing parallel processing.

Comment: I update the number of players by using a simple INSERT query.
$maxPlayersPerTeam is constant in the source code. I execute a query to retrieve the actual number of players and then I compare it to $maxPlayersPerTeam to see if one more player can be added. If so, I add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be happy some people have already worked on this kind of problems and offer you some possible solution : [database transactions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-transaction-model.html).
The best to handle those is to use [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and its [beginTransaction](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.begintransaction.php), [commit](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.commit.php) and [rollBack](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.rollback.php) methods.

Your tables will have to be using a database engine which accept transactions (so innoDb instead of MyISAM).

Answer (score 1):

You should acquire a lock on the dataset (i hope you're using a database, right?), execute your check and eventually update the dataset. So if two people really execute the code simultaneously, one of both has to wait for the lock of the other one. After acquiring the lock a second time the dataset has already been updated and the person can't join your team also.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a database to store the information your database system should have method for transactional processing and managing them which would cater for the events of multiple transactions occuring at the same time (even if this is an incredibly rare case). There's a wiki article on this (even if I hestitate to link to it). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transaction_processing.

MySQL has methods for doing this: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html. As does PostgreSQL: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/tutorial-transactions.html.